# libgtk2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not going to

Tags: package-management, dpkg, dependencies

It seems to my newbie mind that this is something that should be simple to fix.

Please advise

```
    libgtk2.0-0:i386 : Depends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.6.2) but it is not going to be installed
     libpulse0:i386 : Depends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libsystemd0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Requested output for `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0:i386 libcups2:i386 libpulse0:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libsystemd0:i386`:

```
libgtk2.0-0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.24.32-3ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.24.32-3ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages
libcups2:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.8-5ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
     2.2.8-5ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-proposed/main i386 Packages
     2.2.8-5ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages
libpulse0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:12.2-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
     1:12.2-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages
libdbus-1-3:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.12.10-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1.12.10-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages
libsystemd0:i386:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 239-7ubuntu10.5
  Version table:
     239-7ubuntu10.5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-proposed/main i386 Packages
     239-7ubuntu10 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main i386 Packages
```

I believe I have corrected the issue.

Comment: It seems that you should check that you have enabled *security* component of the repositories. What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 18.10
Release: 18.10
Codename: cosmic

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libgtk2.0-0:i386 libcups2:i386 libpulse0:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libsystemd0:i386` to the question.

Comment: Added.  I believe I have solved the issue.  Agree?

Comment: It seems that packages are now available. But consider to check that you have enabled `cosmic-updates` and `cosmic-security` in Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`).